# Wordpress ... Forcing 3rd party plugins to use a theme font styling css?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress-theming, wordpress

It seems to me that there should be Wordpress plugin or hack that forces 3rd party plugins to inherit css font styling values such as font-family, weight, color, line-height etc other than re-writing values to a child theme.

It is such a chore to dig through plugin css and js files Anyone know of anything that does this?

Answer (score 0):

For the css you could try using the css editor in the Jetpack plugin.
If a plugin has a div with text called "textdiv" then you can enter

```
#textdiv{
color:#000}
```

etc into the jetpack css editor and it will override the plugins theme.